# Converting found array keys into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array

```
$array = array(
    "one" => "bar",
    "two"    => "21",
    "three"    => "22",
    "four"    => "25",
    "five" => array(
         "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         ),
        "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" => array(
             "ar1" => "food",
             "ar2" => "dr",
             "ar3" => "ch",
             "ar4" => "ju"
         )),
    "six" => "et",
    "seven" => "op",
    "eight" => "hjs",
    "nine" => array(
         "1" => array(
             "ar5" => "food",
             "ar87" => "dr",
             "ar21" => "ch",
             "ar443" => "ju"
         ),
         "2" => array(
             "73" => "food",
             "82" => "dr",
             "90" => "ch",
             "2123" => "ju"
         )),
    "ten" => "bar",
    "eleven" => "bar",
    "twelve" => "bar"
);
```

and am finding all the array keys at a given level like this

```
foreach ($array['five'] as $keyed=> $user) {
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
       echo "Key: $key; Value: $value Keyed: $keyed<br />\n";
}
}
```

However,i would like to get all the found array keys for use in `array_key_exists` so i need to convert the found keys to array.I am trying that by having this array

```
function the_keys($val){
foreach ($val['five'] as $keyed=> $user) {
foreach ($user as $key => $value) {
    $keyed = array();
}
}
}
```

but even that does not cast the found keys into an array as i had thought.What do i need to do to cast the found keys to array?.

Comment: Do you want do get all `$keyed` into an array?

Comment: Yes,i wan't it into an array.

Comment: So all you care about, in example given, is that x or y get placed into an array for further access at a later time?  Not what x or y contain within them, that can be determined later?

Comment: So for "level five" you want to have an array('xxx...', 'yyy...') ??

Comment: An example of what you want the final output to be would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all keys from `$val['five']` you can use `array_keys()`:

```
$keyed = array_keys($val['five']);
```

You don't need a loop in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would solve your problem

```
foreach($val['five'] as $arrFive) {
    //Here you have both arrays
    foreach($arrFive as $arrXXXX) {
        //Parse array with index xxxx
    }
    foreach($arrFive as $arrYYYY) {
        //Parse array with index yyyy
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear how this would help - you are just looping over the same array (`$arrFive`) twice...

Comment: `$arrFive` contains both arrays. The inner loop extracts contents of the array with index xxxxxxx, meanwhile the other inner loop extracts contents of the array with index yyyy

Comment: That's not what this code does - `$arrFive` has the same value in both inner loops, so they are both looping over the same data. The first time round the *outer* loop, `$arrFive` will be the xxx... array, the second time the yyy... array, but you don't need to write any code twice for that, that's just what a `foreach` loop does. By having two inner loops, you are simply visiting every item twice.

Comment: Here's [a live demo based on your code](http://codepad.viper-7.com/340KFU). I've changed the values in the array slightly so that it's a bit easier to see what's going on.